# Show, using the rational root test, that $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational, for any positive prime $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

> Show, using the rational root test, that $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational, for any positive prime $p$.

The lecturer specifically asks that he wants us to show the above question, through showing that $$x^2 = p \implies x^2-p=0$$ has no rational root. In order to do so, we use a proof by contradiction.

Suppose, to the contrary that $\frac rs$ is a rational solution with $s\neq 0$. Then we must have that $r \mid(-p)$ and $s\mid1$.

I need help trying to find the contradiction here. I know, if $r \mid (-p)$ then, $-p=rk$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. I am completely stuck :/ .

Comment: Notice that since $s|1$ and we can assume $s>0$, $s=1$ and therefore $\frac{r}{s}=r$ so $r^2=p$.

Comment: @user290425 If $r \mid -p$ then $r \mid p$. Since $p$ is prime $r = \pm 1$ or $\pm p$. Why is this the case? If not $-p = rm$ where $m \not = 1$, i.e $p$ is composite which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $s\mid 1$ means that every rational root is in fact an integer root. Can $\sqrt p$ be an integer?
 - Or regarding $r\mid (-p)$, what do you know about the divisors of primes?

Comment: If $r~ | (-p) $ then $-p=rk$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, that is $p= -rk$, but since $p$ is prime, we know it's only divisors are $\pm 1$ and $p$, but I don't know how to use this to show that $p=-rk$ is impossible?